# Inequality $x^n \leq ax + b$, prove inequality for $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have to solve the following exercise.

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers and $n$ a natural number with $n\geq 2$. Prove the following statement:

For all positive real numbers $x$ that satisfy $$x^n \leq ax + b$$ also $$x < \sqrt[n-1]{2a} + \sqrt[n]{2b}$$ holds.

I tried proof by induction which lead me nowhere. Could you give me a hint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : What happens when $ax\leq b$ ? And when $ax \geq b$ ?

Comment: With your hint I could solve it. Thank you very much!